# Creating Background Image for Android App - Java

Tags: java, android, image, background, android-linearlayout

I'm just getting started with android development and I need help with background images. I want to be able to have a background image and then overlay other items (buttons, text, etc.) on top of that background with a layout. I used a LinearLayout just for the sake of being simple and because I don't know what's best for me at the moment.

Anyways, I can't get an image to display using the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class NewGameActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/assets/images/androidBackground.png"));
    this.setContentView(ll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29

This is the preferred way of accessing drawable resources. The image_name is a png image in your drawable or drawable-mdpi folder.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured out how to do it in XML as well.

Answer (score 1):

yes if you are using XML then find the id of that linearlayout like

```
ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1)
```

Then set its background as

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

else here as your code given here you can directly go for

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```