# How to set up a simple button that opens a new Activity in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just need to know how to open a new Activity by clicking on a button. Also, how do you change the background or insert an image into the Activity view?

Comment: There are already plenty of answers on SO ... just search for them, you'll find them...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482337/using-button-to-open-new-view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801716/creating-background-image-for-android-app-java

Comment: Read the [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean Activities by "new screens". Well:

1. With the new ADT v. 20 it is very easy. Right-click on your project and then click on new -> other:
   [image]
2. Click on Android Activity:
   [image]
3. Now Name your Class
4. Start the Activity from your first Activity  like this:

   `Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonId);
       btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

   ```
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent i;
                   Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
               }
           });
   ```

You can change the background image of a Layout by setting this in your Parent View:

```
android:background="@drawable/anyImage"
```

or

```
android:background="#ffffff" //white
```